# Find the polynomial $p(x)$ such that $p(p(x)) = xp(x)+x^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Find the polynomial $p(x)$ such that $p(p(x)) = xp(x)+x^2$.

First, we let $p(x) = a_0 x^n + a_1 x^{n - 1} + a_2 x^{n - 2} + \cdots + a_n x^0$. Then, on the left side of the given equation we get the term $a_0^2 x^{n^2} + a_n$ and some other terms that aren't so important. Because the right side is divisible by $x$, the left side must also be divisible by $x$. Because all terms in $p(p(x))$ except for $a_n$ are divisible by $x$, we know that $a_n$ must be $0$. That is, $p(x)$ has no constant term.

Next, we look at the degree of $p(x)$. We get that $n^2 = \max(n + 1, 2)$. None of these choices give integer solutions.

However, the degree of $xp(x) + x^2$ can also be less than $\max(n + 1, 2)$. One example is $p(x) = -x$. So, we need the degree of $p(p(x))$ to be less than $\max(n + 1, 2)$. If $p(p(x)) = n^2$ is less than $n + 1$, then $n^2 - n - 1 < 0$. So, $\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} < n < \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$. This means that $n$ can only be $1$ or $0$.

If $n = 0$, then the left hand side is a constant, while the right hand side is a quadratic. This cannot satisfy the problem statement, so we move on to the next case.

If $n = 1$, then $p(x)$ must be in the form $kx$ for some constant $k$ because $p(x)$ has no constant term. Plugging $p(x) = kx$ into the given equation, $k^2x = kx^2 + x^2$. Cancelling $x$ out gives $k^2 = (k + 1)x$. Because the left hand side is a constant, the right hand side must also be a constant. So, $k + 1 = 0$ and $k = -1$. However, this means that $1 = 0$ which is obviously false.

I conclude that there are no solutions, but the problem says that there has to be exactly one solution.

Comment: There is a degree one polynomial satisfying the identity, $p(x)=1-x.$

Comment: You made a mistake with the constant term of $p$. You wrote "because $p(x)$ has no constant term". This is false.

Comment: Why is the first part wrong where it showed that it has no constant term?

Comment: $\deg(p+q)\le\max\{\deg p,\,\deg q\}$; you can't in general change the $\le$ to $=$ as the leading terms of $p,\,q$ may cancel if $\deg p=\deg q$.

Comment: What you have given is mostly Correct , except that you (wrongly) assumed $kx+0$ , where you should check whether $kx+c$ gives a Solution. (A) It may eventually imply $c=0$ , then you have shown that your unproven assumption was right. (B) It may instead give you the Solution !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If $n = 1$, then $p(x)$ must be in the form $kx$ for some constant $k$ because $p(x)$ has no constant term.

It is not sufficient to claim this. It is true that the RHS $xp(x)+x^2$ has no constant term. But for LHS, if we take the general form $p(x)=kx+b$, we get

$$p(p(x))=k(kx+b)+b=k^2x+kb+b$$

So it is still possible for LHS has no constant term. For example, if $kb+b=0$, equivalently, either $b=0$ or $k=-1$. What you have done is to exclude $b=0$. But it is still possible for $k=-1\land b\neq 0$. You still need to discuss this case and get the final conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

> Find a polynomial $p(x)$ which satisfies $p^2(x)=xp(x)+x^2.$

\begin{align}
& \text{let } \deg(p)=n. \\
\Rightarrow \; & \deg(LHS)=n^2, \deg(RHS)\leq\max\{n+1, 2\}. \\
\therefore\; & n^2\leq\max\{n+1, 2\}. \\
\Rightarrow \; & n^2 \leq 2 \text{ or } n^2\leq n+1. \\
\Rightarrow \; & n \leq 1. \\
\ \\
\text{Case 1. } & n=1: \\
& \text{let } p(x)=ax+b. \\
\Rightarrow \; & a(ax+b)+b=x(ax+b)+x^2. \\
\therefore \; & (-a-1)x^2+(a^2-b)x+b(a+1)=0. \\
\Rightarrow\; & a=-1, b=1 \Rightarrow p(x)=1-x. \\
\ \\
\text{Case 2. } & n=0: \\
& c=cx+x^2, \text{Contradiction.} \\
\ \\
\therefore \; & \boxed{p(x)=1-x \text{ is the only solution.}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If $\deg p=1$ then $\deg (p\circ p)=1.$ Thus $p$ must be of the form $p(x)=a-x$ in order to eliminate $x^2$ on RHS. Then we get $p(p(x))=x$ and $xp(x)+x^2 =ax.$ Hence $a=1.$ Thus $p(x)=1-x$ is the only solution, mentioned in the first comment to OP.